# checking to see if an arg is a file and printing accordingly

Tags: bash, shell-script, cat

I have the following code that takes in a file via an arg and if none exists, take it from stdin:

```
file=
column=
pattern=
path=
cmd="echo"

while getopts "f:c:e:" opt; do
        case $opt in
                f) file="$OPTARG";;
                c) column="$OPTARG";;
                e) pattern="$OPTARG";;
                *) echo "Usage: $0 -f [file] -c [column] -e [pattern]"
        esac
done

if [ -z "$file" ]; then
        file=$(cat)
fi
```

the problem with this approach is, cat won't work on non-files so if it were taken in from stdout for example:

```
cat data.csv | ./read.sh -c 2 -e " Max"
```

then I won't be able to run:

```
cat "$file"
```

inside the bash script, I'd have to use echo instead.

OTOH, if it is a file, I can use cat and everything is fine. My question is how to do i make the script able to recognize whether or not the var $file is an actual filename or stdout.

Edited: I've taken into account the comments and answers, here's my entire script of how I read to the user their specified column and regex and account for them both passing in a file from stdin or as an arg:

```
#!/bin/bash

unset -v column pattern filepath
cmd=echo

DELIMITER=","

while getopts "f:c:e:" opt; do
        case $opt in
                f) file="$OPTARG";;
                c) column="$OPTARG";;
                e) pattern="$OPTARG";;
                *) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usag: $0 [-f file] [-c column] [-e pattern]"; exit 1
        esac
done

if [ -z "$file" ]; then
        file=$(cat)
elif [ -z "$column" ]; then
        echo "column number neeeded!"
elif [ -z "$pattern" ]; then
        echo "pattern needed!"
fi

if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        cmd="cat"
fi

if [ "$column" -eq 5 ]; then
        DELIMITER=":"
fi

"$cmd" "$file" | awk -v col="$column" -v pattern="$pattern" -v del="$DELIMITER" -F "$DELIMITER" '{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
                if ( i == col && $i == pattern ) {
                        print $0
                } else if ( del == ":" && $i == pattern ) {
                        print $0
                }
        }       
}'

exit 0
```

it works, but I'm sure its not the right approach. once again, I'm trying to let my file do both:

```
cat data.csv | ./read.sh -c 2 -e "Max"
```

and:

```
./read.sh -f data.csv -c 2 -e "Max"
```

the script above works, but optimization is ofc the name of the game!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question; `cat` will read from stdin (or, indeed, other non-files, such as block/character devices); it reads stdin by default if you don't give it a filename to work on, or if you specify `-` as the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `cat`, `-` means stdin. On many systems `/dev/stdin` would work with any command, not just `cat`, while on Linux or Cygwin, `/dev/stdin` would point to the same file as open on stdin, not behaving exactly the same as stdin in several cases.

So you could do:

```
file=-
unset -v column pattern filepath
cmd=echo

while getopts f:c:e: opt; do
  case $opt in
    (f) file="$OPTARG";;
    (c) column="$OPTARG";;
    (e) pattern="$OPTARG";;
    (*) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 [-f file] [-c column] [-e pattern]"; exit 1
  esac
done
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

cat -- "$file"
```

Beware you'll be able to read stdin (`-`) only once.

Also note:

- errors should go to stderr
- `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data (such as `$0` upon which you have no control).
- `[...]` in usage messages by convention means *optional*, so with `-f [file]`, you're implying `-f` is required but its argument is optional which is not true here.
- avoid naming a variable `path` if that script might end up being interpreted in `zsh` (when not in `sh` emulation), where `$path` is the array variable tied to `$PATH` like in `csh`/`tcsh`.
- you should avoid testing for empty values to check whether an argument was provided. For instance, with `-f ''`, you'd get an empty `$file` even though the user explicitly passed an argument to `-f` (admittedly a bogus one for a file path here). Instead, use `unset -v var` in the initialisation to make sure the variable is unset, and check for `[ -z "${var+set}" ]` to check whether it's still unset afterwards. Or use extra boolean flag variables to record whether the option was passed or not.
- if you want to allow the user to pass a file called `-` and mean the actual file called `-` in the current working directory, not stdin, you'd transform it to `./-` in the part that handles `(f)`.
- `file=$(cat)` reads what can be read from stdin and stores it in the `file` variable (in memory). So as others have already said the name of the variable is a bit misleading as that's the input file's contents you get. But also it's the *mangle* contents you get as `$(...)` removes all trailing newline characters and except in zsh removes or chokes on NUL characters. If you use `echo` (which again cannot be used for arbitrary data) on it, `echo` will do its own mangling.

Here you could also take the reverse approach and open the file passed as argument to `-f` on stdin:

```
unset -v column pattern filepath
cmd=echo

while getopts f:c:e: opt; do
  case $opt in
    (f) exec < "$OPTARG";;
    (c) column="$OPTARG";;
    (e) pattern="$OPTARG";;
    (*) printf>&2 '%s\n' "Usage: $0 [-f file] [-c column] [-e pattern]"; exit 1
  esac
done
shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

cat
```

Note that POSIX shells would exit automatically when `exec` fails to open the file. If passed more than one `-f` option, like when assigning `$file`, only the last one will be taken into account.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I truly appreciate all the extra info about the mistakes I'm making that aren't related to the question. I added to the original question with my current method to print echo if its file contents from stdin or a file as an arg, can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question, you can use `test` to see if it is a file. so

```
if [ -z "$file" ] ; then
    echo no file specified
elif [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    echo given a valid file "$file"
else
    echo Given "$file" but it is not a file
fi
```

However I think this is missing the point, you have `file=$(cat)` and I think you are being confused by the reuse of the `file` variable name. If instead you said `file_contents=$(cat)` then I think you will find things clearer.

Comment: how would i read the contents of a file that was provided as an arg? is this going to work: file="$OPTARG";;? or will that just store the name of the file? and if so, how would i get the files contents?

Comment: When the question was originally posted it didn't show the processing that was being done on the contents of the file or stdin. As such it was hard to make a reasonable guess about what was needed. Now we have the details. As the other answer has shown you, you can avoid reading the file into a shell variable and always use `cat` to copy the file, using a filename of `-` if you want to read from stdin. Yes `file=$OPTIND` stores the value given on the command line, the filename, into the variable `file`.

Comment: I've written the following to test it works:  ``` 1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 file=-
  4 
  5 while getopts f: opt; do
  6    case $opt in
  7       f) file="$OPTARG";;
  8    esac
  9 done
 10 
 11 shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"
 12 
 13 cat - - "$file" | grep Max``` This code works only with cat data.csv | ./read.sh and not with ./read.sh -f data.csv